# How can I play on a China Rising server in Battlefield 4?

Tags: battlefield-4

I have update 4 and the China Rising expansion pack, but when I try to play on a China Rising server it asks me to download either the Premium Pack or China Rising. How do I get into a China Rising server?

Comment: It depends if you want the painfull way or the happy not so painfull way. If you run really fast headfirst in a wall that might get you into a coma, or you can try drinking yourself into a coma?

Comment: Anyway, are you sure you have china rising? Is there a little china rising icon in your bf4 profile?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify what platform you're on. If you're on Xbox, delete all of the updates for BF4, clear your xbox cache, restart xbox then manually navigate from the Xbox dashboard to the Xbox live marketplace and search BF4 then download all of the recent updates. It's recommended to download them manually like this instead of from the BF4 store Menu as I've heard this has caused some issues. And if it asks you to pay for China rising for some strange reason then go into your recent downloads and get it from there. If that still doesn't work call 1-800-4my-xbox or go to xbox live support site and they'll give you a new code for china rising.

Comment: Sorry, yea it is an Xbox 360